# jQuery code doesn't open Select Box on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open Select Box on focus. I searched a lot about it, even on stackOverflow. Most of the suggestions were that you can't open it directly. Then I tried one simple approach which we use to open any select box on the browser. Using **(Alt + Down Arrow)** with jQuery. But it is not working. Following is the code snippet:

```
$("select").focus(function(){
   var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 40; // # Down Arrow key code
    e.altKey = true;
    $(this).trigger(e);
    console.log(e);
});
```

It logs an event properly. Can anyone help me to solve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/GR9jU/

Comment: It is working well in chrome. Not working in Firefox